# Splitting rows and moving to csv lines in Excel

Tags: excel

I have data looking like this:

```
John
1231231234
john@email.com
Bob
1241241244
bob@email.com
```

I would like to have it look like this

```
john, 1231231234, john@email.com
Bob, 1241241244, bob@email.com
```

What's the easiest way to do so in Excel?

Comment: is it always 3 lines and what version of excel?

Comment: To transpose columns to rows, you can select and copy the data you wish to transpose, and Paste it into a new row, by right-clicking on a new cell and choosing "Transpose" from the "Paste Special..." menu. Very manual, but efficient if this is a quick task you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Note this assumes 3 cells per as a pattern:

Office 365/2019:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+1):INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+3))
```

[image]

Older:

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+1)<>"",INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+1) & ", " & INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+2) & ", " & INDEX(A:A,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*3+3),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option if you need result into separate columns:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW()-1)*3+COLUMN(A1))
```

Copy to the right and down.

[image]